# How to Preserve last most directory structure when copying files using find

Tags: linux, shell, find, cp

How to Preserve last most directory structure when copying files using find?
Using "parents" command help but it copies complete directory sturucture , whereas I need to preserve only the last most directory

```
find /tmp/data/ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cp --parents {} /u01/ABC/ \;
```

Output that I get:

```
/u01/ABC/tmp/data/a/1.txt
/u01/ABC/tmp/data/b/1.txt
/u01/ABC/tmp/data/c/1.txt
```

Output that I need:

```
/u01/ABC/a/1.txt
/u01/ABC/b/1.txt
/u01/ABC/c/1.txt
```

Comment: This may be better suited for https://unix.stackexchange.com/